# spring: authenticate a user by JWT once and allow access for the rest of the session

Tags: spring, session, jwt

I am using Spring boot and trying to create a page which accepts a JWT and authenticates the user. I have successfully done this using a custom OncePerRequestFilter. this solution requires the user to supply the jwt everytime. but now I want the user to authenticate once using jwt and be able to access the protected resources without supplying the JWT for the rest of the session. what should I do now?

with following code since sessionCreation mode is set to STATELESS in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, we will get http 403(unauthorized access) if we do not supply the jwt.
on the other hand, having removed this line:

> ```
>       .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
> ```

I send a request supplying jwt once. afterward I send a request without jwt and this time I do not get an access denied. I get http 500 Internal Server Error.

stack Trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at jwt.JwtTokenVerifier.doFilterInternal(JwtTokenVerifier.java:43) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1579) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_231]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_231]
```

OncePerRequestFilter

```
public class JwtTokenVerifier extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String token = "";
        try {
            token = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        if (token != "")
            if (token.isEmpty() || token == null || !token.startsWith("Bearer ")) {

                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
                return;
            }

        try {
            token = token.replace("Bearer ", "");
            Algorithm alg = Algorithm.HMAC512("fStrongPassWordfStrongPassWordfStrongPassWord");
            JWTVerifier verifier = JWT.require(alg).withIssuer("auth0").build(); // Reusable verifier instance
            DecodedJWT jwt = verifier.verify(token);

            String username = jwt.getSubject();
            Claim c = jwt.getClaim("auths");
            String[] auths = c.asArray(String.class);

            Set<GrantedAuthority> ga = new HashSet<>();

            for (int i = 0; i < auths.length; i++) {
                ga.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(auths[i]));
            }

            Authentication authn = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, null, ga);
            // isAuthenticated(

            SecurityContext sc = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
            sc.setAuthentication(authn);
//          SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authn);
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
            session.setAttribute(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY, sc);

        } catch (JWTVerificationException exception) {
            throw new ServletException(String.format("invalid token supplied:\n%s", token));

        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);

    }

}
```

the filter to authenticate user using jwt:

```
public class jwtUsrPassAuthFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter{


    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;



    public jwtUsrPassAuthFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        super();
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            UserPassPostObj userpass = new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(), UserPassPostObj.class);

            Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userpass.getUsername(), userpass.getPassword());
            return authenticationManager.authenticate(auth);

        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }




        return super.attemptAuthentication(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain,
            Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {

        System.out.println("appending the token to response\n\n\n");


        String[] grant_auth = new String[authResult.getAuthorities().size()];
        Object[] grants=authResult.getAuthorities().toArray();
        for(int i=0;i<authResult.getAuthorities().size();i++) {

            grant_auth[i]= grants[i].toString();
        }

        Algorithm alg = Algorithm.HMAC512("fStrongPassWordfStrongPassWordfStrongPassWord");
        String token =JWT.create()
            .withIssuer("auth0")
            .withSubject(authResult.getName())
            .withArrayClaim("auths", grant_auth)
            .withIssuedAt(new Date())
            .withExpiresAt(java.sql.Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now().plusDays(30)))
            .sign(alg)
            ;

        System.out.println(token);


        response.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+ token );


    }
}
```

we add the filters in websecurity:

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

PasswordEncoder passEncoder = PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .addFilter(new jwtUsrPassAuthFilter(authenticationManager()))
        .addFilterAfter(new JwtTokenVerifier(), jwtUsrPassAuthFilter.class)
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/", "/login**", "/webjars/**","/css/**","/js/**","/tst1").permitAll()
        .anyRequest()           
        .authenticated()
        ;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question. removing the line I mentioned was enough to force spring to keep the user authenticated during the rest of the session. apparently by default the SessionCreationPolicy is IF_REQUIRED. this is the same as using the following code inside WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:

> .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)

the problem was a null pointer exception which I solved like this:

```
public class JwtTokenVerifier extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String token = "";
        try {
//          token = request.getHeader("Authorization");
            token = request.getParameter("authorization");
            if (token == "" || token==null) {
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
                return;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        if (token.isEmpty() || token == null || !token.startsWith("Bearer")) {

            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        try {
            token = token.replace("Bearer", "");
            Algorithm alg = Algorithm.HMAC512("fuckingStrongPassWordfuckingStrongPassWordfuckingStrongPassWord");
            JWTVerifier verifier = JWT.require(alg).withIssuer("auth0").build(); // Reusable verifier instance
            DecodedJWT jwt = verifier.verify(token);

            String username = jwt.getSubject();
            Claim c = jwt.getClaim("auths");
            String[] auths = c.asArray(String.class);

            Set<GrantedAuthority> ga = new HashSet<>();

            for (int i = 0; i < auths.length; i++) {
                ga.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(auths[i]));
            }

            Authentication authn = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, null, ga);
            // isAuthenticated(

            SecurityContext sc = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
            sc.setAuthentication(authn);
//          SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authn);
//          HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
//          session.setAttribute(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY, sc);

        } catch (JWTVerificationException exception) {
            throw new ServletException(String.format("invalid token supplied:\n%s", token));

        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);

    }

}
```